# Is there an alternative to canvas.getImageData()?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, getimagedata

I am using javascript to read and manipulate pixel data in an image loaded onto a canvas.  The problem is that whenever I call the .getImageData() function, I get a security error in my browser relating to having a tainted canvas.  Setting the crossOrigin to "anonymous" and "use-credentials" dont work.  Neither does using canvas.toDataURL. I have tried converting my image to bit64, and it didnt seem to work either (maybe I implemented it wrong).  Is there any alternative to using canvas to read and manipulate pixel data in an image?

Comment: No, there is no alternative to `.getImageData()` or `toDataUrl()`. See [Allowing cross-origin use of images and canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image).

Comment: The problem is that you are loading an image from a different domain. If you host the image where you host your pages and JavaScript, it will work.